# bash script, to use a variable in a variable

Tags: bash, variables

In order to obtain the results of consecutive numbers, a bash script was created as follows.
However, the results did not come out as intended.

```
#!/bin/bash

test="i am $i"

for i in {1..10}
do
        echo "$test"
done
```

result

```
sh test.sh

i am 
i am 
i am 
i am 
i am 
i am 
i am 
i am 
i am 
i am
```

But the result I want is...
As shown below, how do we deal with the variables to get the results?

```
i am 1
i am 2
i am 3 
i am 4
i am 5
i am 6
i am 7
i am 8
i am 9
i am 10
```

Comment: `$i` is expanded as part of assignment, use `echo i am $i` instead.

Comment: Variables contain static strings, not dynamic instructions for generating strings, so fundamentally this won't work. But this seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Depending on what the bigger picture is (what the larger problem you're trying to solve is), a function might be a good solution, or maybe a `printf` format string, or... I dunno. What's the actual goal here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$i` outside of the variable

```
#!/bin/bash

test="i am "

for i in {1..10}
do
  echo $test $i
done
```

Also you can use `${i}` inside of the variable

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..10}
do
  test="i am ${i}"
  echo $test
done
```

The result is:

```
i am  1
i am  2
i am  3
i am  4
i am  5
i am  6
i am  7
i am  8
i am  9
i am  10
```

Or you can replace substr with anything you want inside.

For example

```
#!/bin/bash
test="I am SUBSTR"

for i in {1..10}
do
  echo ${test/SUBSTR/$i}
done
```

When you have multiple variables, I know this solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
test="I am SUBSTR and STR2"

for i in {1..10}
do
  o=${test/SUBSTR/$i}
  echo ${o/STR2/$i*$i}
done
```

Using `sed` also can help

```
#!/bin/bash
test="I am SUBSTR and STR2"

for i in {1..10}
do
  echo $test | sed  -e 's/SUBSTR/'$i'/;s/STR2/'$i++'/'
done
```

Comment: Can't you split the parts before and after that variable? `part1 $variable part2` ??

Comment: Thank you.
You should use $i in the middle of the sentence.
We want to use $i as the where condition for the DB query.
Is there any way to declare and use the $test externally?

Comment: I updated my answer, You can replace your substr with the variable. @user1819769

Comment: Thank you once again.
Then, how can we use test="select * from TABLE where A=$i and B="abcd"?

Comment: define test like `test="select * from TABLE where A=COUNTER and B="abcd"` and in loop replace COUNTER with `$i`. Did you try this? @user1819769

Comment: I add a solution with 2 variables inside string, I know it is messy but I hope it helps. search more about replacing in bash. @user1819769

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a function in order to delay the evaluation.

```
#!/bin/bash

message () { echo "i am $1"; }

for i in {1..10}
do
  message $i
done
```

Or the following, if you just want to craft the message.

```
#!/bin/bash

message () { echo "i am $1"; }

for i in {1..10}
do
  test="$(message $i)"
  echo "$test"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

test='i am $i'

for i in {1..10}
do
  eval echo "$test"
done
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash

test='echo "i am $i"'

for i in {1..10}
do
  eval "$test"
done
```

Example:

```
yanyong@master:~$ test='echo "i am $i"'; for i in {1..10}; do eval "$test"; done
i am 1
i am 2
i am 3
i am 4
i am 5
i am 6
i am 7
i am 8
i am 9
i am 10
```

References:

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/eval.1p.html